# Embedded Linux Buildroot A20

Tags: linux, embedded

I am currently trying to build an embedded Linux System with Buildroot.
It works so far, I get a bootable SD Card for my A20 based board.
I included all CAN Drivers & protocols I could find (can can_raw and vcan)
My problem is :
after booting and loggin in as root

I type:

```
 ip link add dev vcan0 type vcan ---- THAT WORKS
```

but

```
 ip link add dev can0 type can
```

produces:

RTNETLIINK answers: Operation not supported

What is wrong ??
Thanks in advance for any ideas.

Comment: if you are sure you've included all the can drivers, try to upgrade iproute2 package.

Comment: In the Buildroot configuration dialog I selected all the CAN Drivers I could find (especially the Allwinner A20 driver which can be explicitly selected). but I did not add any separate driver package. I am quite new to the Buildroot environment, so how do I upgrade iproute2 ??